# Modifying Powershell script output for HTML or Word?

Tags: html, powershell, ms-word

I have 'borrowed' this code from another question; but was wondering if either of the following is possible

1 - Have three columns in the webpage that is generated,

or

2 - Export into Word in a table, three columns wide

```
import-module activedirectory

$d = Get-Date -Format dd.MMM.yyyy

$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:white;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:grey}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:white}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
$a = $a + "<img src=C:\Temp\test.jpg height='100' width='380'></img><br>"

$Pre = "<font size=6>Phone Directory - $d</font size>"
$Post = "<font size=2>Uncontrolled when Printed</font size>"

Get-ADUser -filter "OfficePhone -like '*'" -SearchBase 'OU=Staff, DC=test, DC=net' -Properties sn, GivenName, OfficePhone |
    Select-Object sn, GivenName, OfficePhone |
    Sort-Object sn |
    ConvertTo-Html -head $a -pre $Pre -Post $Post|
    Out-File c:\temp\dir.html

invoke-expression c:\temp\dir.html
```

Comment: What has it done so far?  It looks like a lot of this came from [this technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730936.aspx), which shows the sort of columns you seem to be after.

Comment: At the moment i generates the webpage with a single column of surname / first name / phone number. Is there a way to three columns in either html or word to make it better for printing???